How to efficiently check if specific npm workspace or any of its dependencies changed without installing dependencies?
I have a mono-repo containing multiple nodejs apps and libraries. Using npm workspaces I set up each of these apps/libs to be an npm workspace. This means, I only have one package-lock.json in the project root containing the dependency information for all npm-workspaces in the entire project.
My goal is to cache the test-results of each workspace so that I don't waste time running the tests again when the code and the dependencies didn't change at all.
At first I tried:
CACHE_PATH=/tmp/monorepo-cache
WORKSPACE_PATH=path/to/workspace
CURRENT_HASH=$(tar -C ./ -cf - --sort=name "$WORKSPACE_PATH" | sha256sum)

if [ -f "${CACHE_PATH}/${CURRENT_HASH}" ]; then
    cat "${CACHE_PATH}/${CURRENT_HASH}" # print from cache
else
    npm ci && npm --workspace "$WORKSPACE_PATH" run test | tee ${CACHE_PATH}/${CURRENT_HASH}
fi

But then I noticed that it doesn't re-execute the tests in certain cases where is would be necessary for my usecase:

When a dependency of a dependency changed (E.g. foo@1.0.0 depends on bar@^1.0.0 and between two runs we first have bar@1.0.0 and then bar@1.0.1 while the direct dependency of foo@1.0.0 in the package.json stayed the same)
When a symlinked dependency changed (e.g. npm workspace apps/my-node-app1 depends on ../libs/my-node-lib1 and then my-node-lib1 changes between runs.)

My next idea was to take a super hash of the dependency tree, workspace source code and source code of the workspaces (symlinked) that it depends on:
CACHE_PATH=/tmp/monorepo-cache
WORKSPACE_PATH=path/to/workspace
npm ci
DEP_TREE=$(npm ls --workspace "$WORKSPACE_PATH" --all)
DEP_TREE_HASH=$(echo "$DEP_TREE" | sha1sum)
SYMLINKED_DEPS=$(echo "$DEP_TREE" | grep " -> " | cut -d ">" -f2 | awk '{$1=$1};1')

WORKSPACE_SOURCE_CODE_HASH=$(tar -C ./ -cf - --sort=name "$WORKSPACE_PATH" | sha256sum)
SYMLINKED_DEPS_HASHES=""
for dep in $SYMLINKED_DEPS; do
    DEP_HASH=$(tar -C ./ -cf - --sort=name "${WORKSPACE_PATH}/${dep}" | sha256sum)
    SYMLINKED_DEPS_HASHES="${SYMLINKED_DEPS_HASHES}${DEP_HASH}"
done

CURRENT_HASH=$(echo "${DEP_TREE_HASH}${WORKSPACE_SOURCE_CODE_HASH}${SYMLINKED_DEPS_HASHES}" | sha256sum)

if [ -f "${CACHE_PATH}/${CURRENT_HASH}" ]; then
    cat "${CACHE_PATH}/${CURRENT_HASH}" # print from cache
else
    npm --workspace "$WORKSPACE_PATH" run test | tee ${CACHE_PATH}/${CURRENT_HASH}
fi

The problem with this approach is that I have to run npm ci first before I can determine if I need to execute the tests.
This is very costly in my Gitlab CI pipeline because I always have to run npm ci for every test job before I can check if npm test will be necessary. I tried caching the node_modules, but that causes things to break (some test jobs use different base iamges with different architectures/system dependencies). I then cached the npm cache instead which works, but it is still relatively slow (30s to 3min per test job is spent in npm ci). Given my hardware and extremely huge dependency tree, I don't see a way to further optimize the speed of npm ci. And that's why I'm looking for a method that can just skip the npm ci entirely.
This should be possible with smart enough code since all the information could be extracted from the package-lock.json in the project root in my opinion.

note the low number of watches for npm-workspaces, I would look for a more generic, higher watcher count git tag to swap in. (I have no significant experience with debugging git problems). Good luck.
